# Python: a function without parameters that returns a different and unique number each time it is called

Tags: python, function, parameters

I want to make a function that dispenses a new number (in this case the next whole number) every time it is called without any use of parameters in said function. Is this possible?

i.e the output on the first call would be 1, the next time 2 and so on.

Comment: Parameterless functions is not a problem. For example time.time() takes no parameters (although it is not guaranteed to return a different number each time it is called).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can take a look at [itertools.count](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.count) which does what you're looking for.

If you want to implement it yourself, you can use the code in the code block below the words `Equivalent to:` as your starting point and setting your custom start number and remove the parameters from the function.

Answer (score 0):

You could achieve calling without `()` thought a property:

```
class F(object):
    def __init__(self, v=0):
        self.v = v
    @property
    def next(self):
        self.v += 1
        return self.v

 >>> f = F()
 >>> f.next, f.next, f.next
 (1, 2, 3)
```